# MSQC::mult.chart ignores xlim argument

Tags: r

I computed Hotelling T2 on a normalized dataset and obtained the following chart in R:

[image]

In the chart, I want to study the interval 50-100 in the X-axis closely. Is there any function or method in R through which this can be done? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "stuying"? Restrict the x-Axis to interval (50-100)?

Comment: I want to take a closer look at the points between 50-100

Comment: what do you mean by "take a closer look"? zooming into the figure?extracting the data points from data set? 5-number summary?

Comment: Zooming into the figure. Consider only the points between 50-100 as the x axis of the graph I want.

Comment: can post the r-code that you used to create the figure

Comment: if its base `plot`, you should usually be able to add `xlim=c(50, 100)`

Comment: The code I used is: mult.chart(MD11, type = "t2", alpha = 0.05). MD11 is the name of the dataset. I tried using xlim but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `MSQC::mult.chart` does not support `xlim` argument. But you can extract the values to plot and reproduce manually. See example below.

```r
library(MSQC)
data(dowel1)
# default
mult.chart(dowel1, type = "chi", alpha = 0.05)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "Chi-squared Control Chart"
#> 
#> $ucl
#> [1] 5.99
#> 
#> $t2
#>       [,1]
#>  [1,] 1.62
#> ...
#> 
#> $Xmv
#> [1] 0.5 1.0
#> 
#> $covariance
#>         [,1]    [,2]
#> [1,] 4.9e-05 8.6e-05
#> [2,] 8.6e-05 4.2e-04
```

[image]

```r
# manual
mc <- mult.chart(dowel1, type = "chi", alpha = 0.05)
plot(seq_along(mc$t2), mc$t2, ylim = c(0, mc$ucl), type = "l")
points(seq_along(mc$t2), mc$t2)
abline(h = mc$ucl, col = 2)
```

[image]

```r
# restricted
plot(seq_along(mc$t2), mc$t2, ylim = c(0, mc$ucl), type = "l", xlim = c(5, 20))
points(seq_along(mc$t2), mc$t2)
abline(h = mc$ucl, col = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>